# Laravel Route seems to set my Controller variable to null

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes

I have a `Route` to my `CartController` like this:

```
Route::get('setDropDownIndex/{index}', 'CartController@setDropDownIndex');
```

And in my `CartController`:

```
public function setDropDownIndex($index)
{
  $this->dropDownIndex = $index;
  //echo $this->dropDownIndex;
  return redirect('cart');
}

public function cart()
{
$this->getPayPalOptions();

$data = array(
  'ppCode'  => $this->ppCode,
  'estOmnivaValue'  => $this->estOmnivaValue,
  'estSmartValue'  => $this->estSmartValue,
  'europeValue'  => $this->europeValue,
  'rowValue'  => $this->rowValue,
  'estOmnivaText'  => $this->estOmnivaText,
  'estSmartText'  => $this->estSmartText,
  'europeText'  => $this->europeText,
  'rowText'  => $this->rowText,
  'dropDownIndex' => $this->dropDownIndex
);

return View::make('pages.cart', ['active'=>'navCart'])->with($data);
}
```

The `Route` works just fine and I can `echo` to confirm that `setDropDownIndex` 'saves' `$this->dropDownIndex` properly.  The problem is that my `redirect` to `cart` seems to destroy my `$this->dropDownIndex`, setting it to null.

I'm very new to `Laravel`, can anybody tell me how I can 'persist' `$this->dropDownIndex`?  Should I be using `with` when I do the redirection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For persisting `$index` value you can use session. otherwise after redirecting it will redirect to that routes again it will come to that cart function of this controller and when it will come to `cart()` then it is not going to the setDropDownIndex($index) function. so your variable is not set its better that you can use with() which is [flash](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data) session variable which you can use with the next redirected request

```
return redirect('cart')->with('index', $index);
```

Comment: Thanks!  That makes sense and worked like a charm :-)

Comment: Glad to help @DaveChambers :)